# mistake with eslint with command

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I have this in my package.json:

[image]

When I'm running "npm run analysis", I've got a problem with eslint

[image]

How can I solve this ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks like you are using CRLF (\r\n) as line break and eslint expects LF (\n). It looks like you are using VSCode, VSCode should have a button in the statusbar at the bottom right where you can change the line break type.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close the file with errors (babelrc)
2. run `npm run analysis:lint:eslint --fix`
3. The errors will be fixed with the eslint.

Possible causes:

- Git made it so
- You edited the file and it cot converted to crlf by whatever reason